# What is the order of the Doom Original Series?

Tags: doom-series

I want to play the Original Doom games in chronological order, but after checking the [Wikipedia page for the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_(franchise)), I found that there are a couple of official maps for the Doom games:

- Doom 1

  - Thy Flesh Consumed (from The Ultimate Doom)
  - Sigil (unofficial, by John Romero, the co-founder of id Software)
- Doom 2

  - Master Levels for Doom II
  - Doom II: No Rest for the Living (Xbox 360, by Nerve Software)
- Final Doom

  - TNT: Evilution
  - The Plutonia Experiment
- Doom 64
- Doom 3 / Doom 3: BFG Edition

  - Resurrection of Evil
  - The Lost Mission (BFG Edition only)

What is the correct chronological order for the Original Doom games? Is the chronological order the same as the release order?

Comment: Doom 3 is a soft reboot, so pretty much everything before is in a state of canon limbo.

Comment: Since we're commenting on reboots, Doom 2016 is *another* soft reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official classic canon would be:

DOOM

DOOM - Thy Flesh Consumed

DOOM II

DOOM II - No Rest for the Living

Sigil is unofficial, as are The Master Levels for DOOM II and Plutonia. TNT: Evilution IS considered low-canon, but I'm really not sure where it fits in though. Given the lack of events to gauge context, we'd have to go on the visuals and equipment - this puts it somewhere DURING both DOOM and DOOM II, which seems odd. Between, perhaps?

As mentioned, DOOM 3 is something of a soft-reboot, so you can consider it a recap of the above canon. Play through the above DOOM and DOOM II canon, then play through DOOM 3; it's a more horror-esque and narrative-heavy "remake" of the previous two titles, and overall a really solid game.

Another note; The Ultimate DOOM is a comprehensive collection of DOOM (1) canon